# Why can final constants in Java be overridden?

Tags: java, interface, overriding, final

Consider the following interface in Java:

```
public interface I {
    public final String KEY = "a";
}
```

And the following class:

```
public class A implements I {
    public String KEY = "b";

    public String getKey() {
        return KEY;
    }
}
```

Why is it possible for class A to come along and override interface I's final constant?

Try for yourself:

```
A a = new A();
String s = a.getKey(); // returns "b"!!!
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Despite the fact that you are shadowing the variable it's quite interesting to know that you can change final fields in java as you can read [here](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue096.html):

> **Java 5 - "final" is not final anymore**
>
> Narve Saetre from Machina Networks in Norway sent me a note yesterday,
>   mentioning that it was a pity that we could change the handle to a
>   final array. I misunderstood him, and started patiently explaining
>   that we could not make an array constant, and that there was no way of
>   protecting the contents of an array. "No", said he, "we can change a
>   final handle using reflection."
>
> I tried Narve's sample code, and unbelievably, Java 5 allowed me to
>   modify a final handle, even a handle to a primitive field! I knew that
>   it used to be allowed at some point, but that it was then disallowed,
>   so I ran some tests with older versions of Java. First, we need a
>   class with final fields:
>
> ```
> public class Person {
>   private final String name;
>   private final int age;
>   private final int iq = 110;
>   private final Object country = "South Africa";
>
>   public Person(String name, int age) {
>     this.name = name;
>     this.age = age;
>   }
>
>   public String toString() {
>     return name + ", " + age + " of IQ=" + iq + " from " + country;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **JDK 1.1.x**
>
> In JDK 1.1.x, we were not able to access private fields using
>   reflection. We could, however, create another Person with public
>   fields, then compile our class against that, and swap the Person
>   classes. There was no access checking at runtime if we were running
>   against a different class to the one that we compiled against.
>   However, we could not rebind final fields at runtime using either
>   class swapping or reflection.
>
> The JDK 1.1.8 JavaDocs for java.lang.reflect.Field had the following
>   to say:
>
> - If this Field object enforces Java language access control, and the underlying field is inaccessible, the method throws an
>     IllegalAccessException.
> - If the underlying field is final, the method throws an IllegalAccessException.
>
> **JDK 1.2.x**
>
> In JDK 1.2.x, this changed a bit. We could now make private fields
>   accessible with the setAccessible(true) method. Access of fields was
>   now checked at runtime, so we could not use the class swapping trick
>   to access private fields. However, we could now suddenly rebind final
>   fields! Look at this code:
>
> ```
> import java.lang.reflect.Field;
>
> public class FinalFieldChange {
>   private static void change(Person p, String name, Object value)
>       throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
>     Field firstNameField = Person.class.getDeclaredField(name);
>     firstNameField.setAccessible(true);
>     firstNameField.set(p, value);
>   }
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>     Person heinz = new Person("Heinz Kabutz", 32);
>     change(heinz, "name", "Ng Keng Yap");
>     change(heinz, "age", new Integer(27));
>     change(heinz, "iq", new Integer(150));
>     change(heinz, "country", "Malaysia");
>     System.out.println(heinz);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> When I ran this in JDK 1.2.2_014, I got the following result:
>
> ```
> Ng Keng Yap, 27 of IQ=110 from Malaysia    Note, no exceptions, no complaints, and an incorrect IQ result. It seems that if we set a
> ```
>
> final field of a primitive at declaration time, the value is inlined,
>   if the type is primitive or a String.
>
> **JDK 1.3.x and 1.4.x**
>
> In JDK 1.3.x, Sun tightened up the access a bit, and prevented us from
>   modifying a final field with reflection. This was also the case with
>   JDK 1.4.x. If we tried running the FinalFieldChange class to rebind
>   the final fields at runtime using reflection, we would get:
>
> > java version "1.3.1_12": Exception thread "main"
> >     IllegalAccessException: field is final
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Native Method)
> >             at FinalFieldChange.change(FinalFieldChange.java:8)
> >             at FinalFieldChange.main(FinalFieldChange.java:12)
> >
> > java version "1.4.2_05" Exception thread "main"
> >     IllegalAccessException: Field is final
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:519)
> >             at FinalFieldChange.change(FinalFieldChange.java:8)
> >             at FinalFieldChange.main(FinalFieldChange.java:12)
>
> **JDK 5.x**
>
> Now we get to JDK 5.x. The FinalFieldChange class has the same output
>   as in JDK 1.2.x:
>
> ```
> Ng Keng Yap, 27 of IQ=110 from Malaysia    When Narve Saetre mailed me that he managed to change a final field in JDK 5 using
> ```
>
> reflection, I was hoping that a bug had crept into the JDK. However,
>   we both felt that to be unlikely, especially such a fundamental bug.
>   After some searching, I found the JSR-133: Java Memory Model and
>   Thread Specification. Most of the specification is hard reading, and
>   reminds me of my university days (I used to write like that ;-)
>   However, JSR-133 is so important that it should be required reading
>   for all Java programmers. (Good luck)
>
> Start with chapter 9 Final Field Semantics, on page 25. Specifically,
>   read section 9.1.1 Post-Construction Modification of Final Fields. It
>   makes sense to allow updates to final fields. For example, we could
>   relax the requirement to have fields non-final in JDO.
>
> If we read section 9.1.1 carefully, we see that we should only modify
>   final fields as part of our construction process. The use case is
>   where we deserialize an object, and then once we have constructed the
>   object, we initialise the final fields, before passing it on. Once we
>   have made the object available to another thread, we should not change
>   final fields using reflection. The result would not be predictable.
>
> It even says this: If a final field is initialized to a compile-time
>   constant in the field declaration, changes to the final field may not
>   be observed, since uses of that final field are replaced at compile
>   time with the compile-time constant. This explains why our iq field
>   stays the same, but country changes.
>
> Strangely, JDK 5 differs slightly from JDK 1.2.x, in that you cannot
>   modify a static final field.
>
> ```
> import java.lang.reflect.Field;
>
> public class FinalStaticFieldChange {
>   /** Static fields of type String or primitive would get inlined */
>   private static final String stringValue = "original value";
>   private static final Object objValue = stringValue;
>
>   private static void changeStaticField(String name)
>       throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
>     Field statFinField = FinalStaticFieldChange.class.getDeclaredField(name);
>     statFinField.setAccessible(true);
>     statFinField.set(null, "new Value");
>   }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>     changeStaticField("stringValue");
>     changeStaticField("objValue");
>     System.out.println("stringValue = " + stringValue);
>     System.out.println("objValue = " + objValue);
>     System.out.println();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> When we run this with JDK 1.2.x and JDK 5.x, we get the following
>   output:
>
> > java version "1.2.2_014": stringValue = original value objValue = new
> >     Value
> >
> > java version "1.5.0" Exception thread "main" IllegalAccessException:
> >     Field is final   at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:656)   at
> >     FinalStaticFieldChange.changeStaticField(12)   at
> >     FinalStaticFieldChange.main(16)
>
> So, JDK 5 is like JDK 1.2.x, just different?
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> Do you know when JDK 1.3.0 was released? I struggled to find out, so I
>   downloaded and installed it. The readme.txt file has the date
>   2000/06/02 13:10. So, it is more than 4 years old (goodness me, it
>   feels like yesterday). JDK 1.3.0 was released several months before I
>   started writing The Java(tm) Specialists' Newsletter! I think it would
>   be safe to say that very few Java developers can remember the details
>   of pre-JDK1.3.0. Ahh, nostalgia isn't what it used to be! Do you
>   remember running Java for the first time and getting this error:
>   "Unable to initialize threads: cannot find class java/lang/Thread"?

Comment: It's also possible to change the values of final fields from JNI code.

Answer (score 37):

You are hiding it, it's a feature of "Scope".  Any time you are in a smaller scope, you can redefine all the variables you like and the outer scope variables will be "Shadowed"

By the way, you can scope it again if you like:

```
public class A implements I {
    public String KEY = "b";

    public String getKey() {
        String KEY = "c";
        return KEY;
    }
}
```

Now KEY will return "c";

Edited because the original sucked upon re-reading.

Comment: To expand a bit, you can't override anything but instance methods. Variables and class (static) methods are hidden or shadowed, not overridden.

Comment: Thanks.  I had something about that in my original version, but then realized that he may not have been using "Override" to mean inheritance, he may have just meant "change", so I rephrased it to remove that assumption--but good to have it stated explicitly too.

Comment: +1. Shadowing even means the following `I a = (I) new A(); a.KEY => "a"` since the reference type is crucial in this case.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your class is simply hiding the variable, not overwriting it:

```
public class A implements I {
    public String   KEY = "B";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A t = new A();
        System.out.println(t.KEY);
        System.out.println(((I) t).KEY);
    }
}
```

This will print "B", and "A", as you found. You can even assign to it, as the A.KEY variable  is not defined as final.

```
 A.KEY="C" <-- this compiles.
```

But -

```
public class C implements I{

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        C t = new C();
        c.KEY="V"; <--- compiler error ! can't assign to final

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a design consideration,

```
public interface I {
    public final String KEY = "a";
}
```

The static methods always returns the parent key.

```
public class A implements I {
    public String KEY = "b";

    public String getKey() {
        return KEY; // returns "b"
    }

    public static String getParentKey(){
        return KEY; // returns "a"
    }
}
```

Just like Jom has noticed. The design of static methods using re-defined interface members could be a heavy problem. In general, try to avoid use the same name for the constant.

Answer (score 2):

You should not access your constant in this way, use the static reference instead:

```
I.KEY //returns "a"
B.KEY //returns "b"
```

Comment: You should only do it this way if you're specifically overriding the default access.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields and methods are attached to the class/interface declaring them (though interfaces cannot declare static methods as they are wholly abstract classes which need to be implemented).

So, if you have an interface with a public static (vartype) (varname),
that field is attached to that interface.

If you have a class implement that interface, the compiler trick transforms (this.)varname into InterfaceName.varname.  But, if your class redefines varname, a new constant named varname is attached to your class, and the compiler knows to now translate (this.)varname into NewClass.varname.  The same applies for methods: if the new class does not re-define the method, (this.)methodName is translated into SuperClass.methodName, otherwise, (this.)methodName is translated into CurrentClass.methodName.

This is why you will encounter the warning "x field/method should be accessed in a static way".  The compiler is telling you that, although it may use the trick, it would prefer that you used ClassName.method/fieldName, because it is more explicit for readability purposes.